# Xamarin Deploying failed

Tags: c#, android, macos, xamarin, adb

I was trying to make my own app, but when I try to build and deploy it for testing.
It just gives me some error

```
Done building project "testing.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0137: The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0137: '.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0137: Fast Deployment is not currently supported on this device.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0137: Please file an issue with the exact error message using the 'Help->Send Feedback->Report a Problem' menu item in Visual Studio
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0137: or 'Help->Report a Problem' in Visual Studio for Mac.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0137: Please set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true' to disable Fast Deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages, or edit the project file in a text editor.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:29.30
```

How could I fix it? I haven't do anything to it and just build
My android device is from BlueStacks, and I'm on Mac.
I connect to the BlueStacks device using `adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555` and I have Android Debug Bridge in Bluestacks enabled.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try disable fast deploy as it suggests?

Comment: Try to change configurations in manifest file , refer to the similar thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/516477/i-have-a-new-samsung-galaxy-s20-fe-that-i-want-to.html.